# The application requires that assembly office Version 14.0.0.0 be installed in the GAC first

Tags: c#, .net, interop

I have an application which uses the Word and Excel interop references.  I have a copy of MS Office 2003 and the client machines use Office 2007, and I get this prompt when clients try to install/run the application.

There are a few articles on this however the solutions either seemed specific to the particular issue or were just unresolved. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Please post the _exact_ error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The referenced Office PIA *must be installed* and is therefor a requirement to this particular program.

This would happen if running *any* version of Office, say 2007, if the correctly versioned PIA was not installed. In any case, if the development machine has Office 2003 *and* the Office 14 PIAs this error would not occur because the "version 14" PIAs can be found in the development environment -- even if Office 2010 itself was not installed.

See the [Office 2010 PIA redistributables](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508). I think the "version 14" PIAs might be installed automatically with Office 2010, but I am not certain.

Keep in mind that using PIA methods/properties which are *not* supported by the wrapped COM for the particular Office version will throw a `COMException` at runtime. That is, even if the Office 2003 environment has the 2010 PIAs installed, using 2007+ features might cause other runtime issues.

Happy coding.

Comment: It seems to install fine now!
I just need to work on creating an installer for distribution and then I can test it properly on other machines.

Comment: I'm sorry to ride this question, but it's the best outlet for help atm.
I've created an .exe using Inno to distribute within the organisation and it works fine, but only on machines that have Office versions 2003 and 2010 as far as I can tell.
The application will install, but when attempting to run it displays a most generic error:
"An error has occured when executing the procedure."

Any clue as to what I could be missing?
What information is needed to better find out?

I'll continue fiddling with it in the meantime~